# Recommended timeo setting for NFS hard TCP mounts

Tags: nfs

We're using NFS version 3 TCP hard mounts and trying to tune behavior when there is a network interruption.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs-nfs-mount-settings.html suggests setting timeo=600 (60 seconds) and warns that setting it lower might hurt performance. Any idea as to why?